# Can't find Python executable when installing gulp-converter-tjs

Tags: python, node.js, npm, gulp

I am getting the following error when I attempt to install gulp-converter-tjs

using **npm install -g gulp-converter-tjs**

It looks like I am missing python but the path is correct for python.exe . I can even run python command from my cmd and also enviroment variables are set.
Any suggestions?

> C:\Users\themhz\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\gulp-converter-tjs\node_modules\iconv>if
>   not defined npm_config_node_gy p (node
>   "C:\Users\themhz\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\bin\node-gyp-bin....\node_modules\node-gyp\bin\node-gyp
>   .js" rebuild ) else (node "" rebuild ) gyp ERR! configure error gyp
>   ERR! stack Error: Can't find Python executable
>   "C:\Users\themhz\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\python.exe
>   ", you can set the PYTHON env variable. gyp ERR! stack at
>   PythonFinder.failNoPython
>   (C:\Users\themhz\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-
>   gyp\lib\configure.js:483:19) gyp ERR! stack at PythonFinder.
>   (C:\Users\themhz\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-g
>   yp\lib\configure.js:509:16) gyp ERR! stack at
>   C:\Users\themhz\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\node_modules\graceful-fs\polyfills.js:284:29
>   gyp ERR! stack at FSReqWrap.oncomplete (fs.js:152:21) gyp ERR! System
>   Windows_NT 10.0.15063 gyp ERR! command "C:\Program
>   Files\nodejs\node.exe"
>   "C:\Users\themhz\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\nod
>   e_modules\node-gyp\bin\node-gyp.js" "rebuild" gyp ERR! cwd
>   C:\Users\themhz\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\gulp-converter-tjs\node_modules\iconv
>   gyp ERR! node -v v8.9.1 gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v3.6.2 gyp ERR! not ok
>   npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE npm ERR! errno 1 npm ERR! iconv@2.3.0
>   install: node-gyp rebuild npm ERR! Exit status 1 npm ERR! npm ERR!
>   Failed at the iconv@2.3.0 install script. npm ERR! This is probably
>   not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output
>   above.
>
> npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in: npm ERR!
>   C:\Users\themhz\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache_logs\2017-11-25T15_20_09_146Z-debug.log

My machine is running 
windows 10
npm -v 5.5.1
node -v v8.9.1
Python3

Answer (score 7, accepted):

For those who encounter this problem in future, you can save yourself some time and let npm install all necessary programs by running:

`npm install --global --production windows-build-tools`

**Note**: you need to run this command as administrator

Comment: this does not seem to install python on my computer . Also it looks like I need python 2.7 in order to run gulp-converter-tjs. If you see my command I ran -g which means global right? This is also a dev environment.

Comment: https://www.npmjs.com/package/windows-build-tools - please read their documentation. It does install Python 2.7 and  other tools required to compile native modules. Yes, -g or --global means global, which will give you the possibility to run this package from everywhere. Without -g, this package will be accessible only from the project in which you installed it.

Comment: Can someone please explain what windows-build-tools is all of sudden needed for npm projects in windows? before this date I have never needed it.

Answer (score -1):

I installed the Python 2.7 version and then I installed the visual studio 2017 community edition in order to get the c++ and the .net framework libraries.