# Why am getting, gyp ERR! stack Error: Can't find Python executable "python"?

Tags: python, node.js, angular, angular-cli, node-modules

In my project I didn't use of any `PYTHON`, but am getting `gyp ERR! stack Error: Can't find Python executable "python", you can set the PYTHON env variable.`

Am installing the `node_modules` using `npm i --save`.
recently I update my project so upgrade the `node`, `npm` and `yarn` versions.

Here the versions:

```
node: 12.4.0
npm: 6.9.0
yarn: 1.16.0
@angular/cli: 8.0.2
```

While am installing `node_modules` getting the errors:

```
> node-sass@4.10.0 postinstall 
D:\kishore\Git_Works\jupiter\node_modules\node-sass
> node scripts/build.js

Building: C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe 
D:\kishore\Git_Works\jupiter\node_modules\node-gyp\bin\node-gyp.js rebuild - 
-verbose --libsass_ext= --libsass_cflags= --libsass_ldflags= -- 
libsass_library=
gyp info it worked if it ends with ok
gyp verb cli [
gyp verb cli   'C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe',
gyp verb cli   'D:\\kishore\\Git_Works\\jupiter\\node_modules\\node- 
gyp\\bin\\node-gyp.js',
gyp verb cli   'rebuild',
gyp verb cli   '--verbose',
gyp verb cli   '--libsass_ext=',
gyp verb cli   '--libsass_cflags=',
gyp verb cli   '--libsass_ldflags=',
gyp verb cli   '--libsass_library='
gyp verb cli ]
gyp info using node-gyp@3.8.0
gyp info using node@12.4.0 | win32 | x64
gyp verb command rebuild []
gyp verb command clean []
gyp verb clean removing "build" directory
gyp verb command configure []
gyp verb check python checking for Python executable "python2" in the PATH
gyp verb `which` failed Error: not found: python2
gyp verb `which` failed     at getNotFoundError 

(D:\kishore\Git_Works\jupiter\node_modules\which\which.js:13:12)
gyp verb `which` failed     at F (D:\kishore\Git_Works\jupiter\node_modules\which\which.js:68:19)
gyp verb `which` failed     at E (D:\kishore\Git_Works\jupiter\node_modules\which\which.js:80:29)
gyp verb `which` failed     at D:\kishore\Git_Works\jupiter\node_modules\which\which.js:89:16
gyp verb `which` failed     at D:\kishore\Git_Works\jupiter\node_modules\isexe\index.js:42:5
gyp verb `which` failed     at D:\kishore\Git_Works\jupiter\node_modules\isexe\windows.js:36:5
gyp verb `which` failed     at FSReqCallback.oncomplete (fs.js:165:21)
gyp verb `which` failed  python2 Error: not found: python2
gyp verb `which` failed     at getNotFoundError (D:\kishore\Git_Works\jupiter\node_modules\which\which.js:13:12)
gyp verb `which` failed     at F (D:\kishore\Git_Works\jupiter\node_modules\which\which.js:68:19)
gyp verb `which` failed     at E (D:\kishore\Git_Works\jupiter\node_modules\which\which.js:80:29)
gyp verb `which` failed     at D:\kishore\Git_Works\jupiter\node_modules\which\which.js:89:16
gyp verb `which` failed     at D:\kishore\Git_Works\jupiter\node_modules\isexe\index.js:42:5
gyp verb `which` failed     at D:\kishore\Git_Works\jupiter\node_modules\isexe\windows.js:36:5
gyp verb `which` failed     at FSReqCallback.oncomplete (fs.js:165:21) {
gyp verb `which` failed   stack: 'Error: not found: python2\n    at getNotFoundError ' +
gyp verb `which` failed     '(D:\\kishore\\Git_Works\\jupiter\\node_modules\\which\\which.js:13:12)\n' +
gyp verb `which` failed     '    at F ' +
gyp verb `which` failed     '(D:\\kishore\\Git_Works\\jupiter\\node_modules\\which\\which.js:68:19)\n' +
gyp verb `which` failed     '    at E ' +
gyp verb `which` failed     '(D:\\kishore\\Git_Works\\jupiter\\node_modules\\which\\which.js:80:29)\n' +
gyp verb `which` failed     '    at ' +
gyp verb `which` failed     'D:\\kishore\\Git_Works\\jupiter\\node_modules\\which\\which.js:89:16\n' +
gyp verb `which` failed     '    at ' +
gyp verb `which` failed     'D:\\kishore\\Git_Works\\jupiter\\node_modules\\isexe\\index.js:42:5\n ' +
gyp verb `which` failed     '   at ' +
gyp verb `which` failed     'D:\\kishore\\Git_Works\\jupiter\\node_modules\\isexe\\windows.js:36:5\n' +
gyp verb `which` failed     '    at FSReqCallback.oncomplete (fs.js:165:21)',
gyp verb `which` failed   code: 'ENOENT'
gyp verb `which` failed }
gyp verb check python checking for Python executable "python" in the PATH
gyp verb `which` failed Error: not found: python
gyp verb `which` failed     at getNotFoundError (D:\kishore\Git_Works\jupiter\node_modules\which\which.js:13:12)
gyp verb `which` failed     at F (D:\kishore\Git_Works\jupiter\node_modules\which\which.js:68:19)
gyp verb `which` failed     at E (D:\kishore\Git_Works\jupiter\node_modules\which\which.js:80:29)
gyp verb `which` failed     at D:\kishore\Git_Works\jupiter\node_modules\which\which.js:89:16
gyp verb `which` failed     at D:\kishore\Git_Works\jupiter\node_modules\isexe\index.js:42:5
gyp verb `which` failed     at D:\kishore\Git_Works\jupiter\node_modules\isexe\windows.js:36:5
gyp verb `which` failed     at FSReqCallback.oncomplete (fs.js:165:21)
gyp verb `which` failed  python Error: not found: python
gyp verb `which` failed     at getNotFoundError (D:\kishore\Git_Works\jupiter\node_modules\which\which.js:13:12)
gyp verb `which` failed     at F (D:\kishore\Git_Works\jupiter\node_modules\which\which.js:68:19)
gyp verb `which` failed     at E (D:\kishore\Git_Works\jupiter\node_modules\which\which.js:80:29)
gyp verb `which` failed     at D:\kishore\Git_Works\jupiter\node_modules\which\which.js:89:16
gyp verb `which` failed     at D:\kishore\Git_Works\jupiter\node_modules\isexe\index.js:42:5
gyp verb `which` failed     at D:\kishore\Git_Works\jupiter\node_modules\isexe\windows.js:36:5
gyp verb `which` failed     at FSReqCallback.oncomplete (fs.js:165:21) {
gyp verb `which` failed   stack: 'Error: not found: python\n    at getNotFoundError ' +
gyp verb `which` failed     '(D:\\kishore\\Git_Works\\jupiter\\node_modules\\which\\which.js:13:12)\n' +
gyp verb `which` failed     '    at F ' +
gyp verb `which` failed     '(D:\\kishore\\Git_Works\\jupiter\\node_modules\\which\\which.js:68:19)\n' +
gyp verb `which` failed     '    at E ' +
gyp verb `which` failed     '(D:\\kishore\\Git_Works\\jupiter\\node_modules\\which\\which.js:80:29)\n' +
gyp verb `which` failed     '    at ' +
gyp verb `which` failed     'D:\\kishore\\Git_Works\\jupiter\\node_modules\\which\\which.js:89:16\n' +
gyp verb `which` failed     '    at ' +
gyp verb `which` failed     'D:\\kishore\\Git_Works\\jupiter\\node_modules\\isexe\\index.js:42:5\n ' +
gyp verb `which` failed     '   at ' +
gyp verb `which` failed     'D:\\kishore\\Git_Works\\jupiter\\node_modules\\isexe\\windows.js:36:5\n' +
gyp verb `which` failed     '    at FSReqCallback.oncomplete (fs.js:165:21)',
gyp verb `which` failed   code: 'ENOENT'
gyp verb `which` failed }
gyp verb could not find "python". checking python launcher
gyp verb could not find "python". guessing location
gyp verb ensuring that file exists: C:\Python27\python.exe
gyp ERR! configure error
gyp ERR! stack Error: Can't find Python executable "python", you can set the PYTHON env variable.
gyp ERR! stack     at PythonFinder.failNoPython (D:\kishore\Git_Works\jupiter\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\configure.js:484:19)
gyp ERR! stack     at PythonFinder.<anonymous> (D:\kishore\Git_Works\jupiter\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\configure.js:509:16)
gyp ERR! stack     at D:\kishore\Git_Works\jupiter\node_modules\graceful-fs\polyfills.js:282:31
gyp ERR! stack     at FSReqCallback.oncomplete (fs.js:165:21)
gyp ERR! System Windows_NT 10.0.17134
gyp ERR! command "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "D:\\kishore\\Git_Works\\jupiter\\node_modules\\node-gyp\\bin\\node-gyp.js" "rebuild" "--verbose" "--libsass_ext=" "--libsass_cflags=" "--libsass_ldflags=" "--libsass_library="
gyp ERR! cwd D:\kishore\Git_Works\jupiter\node_modules\node-sass
gyp ERR! node -v v12.4.0
gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v3.8.0
gyp ERR! not ok
Build failed with error code: 1
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@1.2.9 (node_modules\fsevents):
npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for fsevents@1.2.9: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"win32","arch":"x64"})

npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! node-sass@4.10.0 postinstall: `node scripts/build.js`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the node-sass@4.10.0 postinstall script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\IEUI18-1\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2019-06-21T10_25_49_347Z-debug.log

D:\kishore\Git_Works\jupiter>
```

Can anyone help me out to solve this problem?

Comment: You don't have python2 on your PATH. Make sure you install python2, and make sure its on your PATH. The error is pretty clear. One of your node dependencies clearly is using python in it's build process, even if you didn't use it in your project.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can't find Python executable when installing gulp-converter-tjs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47494142/cant-find-python-executable-when-installing-gulp-converter-tjs)

Answer (score 1):

Execute below command in the command prompt with **admin** rights

```
npm --add-python-to-path='true' --debug install --global windows-build-tools
npm install --global node-gyp
```

After executing the command, delete the `package-lock.json` and node modules folder, then do the `npm install` again.

**Bug request already raised here**: https://github.com/JeremyEnglert/JointsWP/issues/317